# 'Animated' 2D scatter

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I want to visualise conversion of filters. I would like to plot a scatter plot, where every half second the next filter's values are plotted.

My objectives are:

1. Plot all values up to point (k) but to have values(k) indicated on the plot.
2. Pause between plotting values for (k) and (k+1)
3. Plot at full screen
4. Have the plot after finishing all iteration

I did a function but it is very inefficient and everything slows down after plotting some values.

The only way I found is to use interactive plot `ion()` and every step plot all points again with updated marker. For each step (k) I would like to rather remove previous points (k-1) and add them in them with different marker and add current points (k)

```
import pylab as pl
import time
xPos1 = pl.arange(100)
m1 = [pl.sin(pl.pi*x/10) for x in xPos1]
m2 = [pl.cos(pl.pi*x/30) for x in xPos1]
m3 = [pl.sin(pl.pi*x/20) for x in xPos1]
trueVal1 = [0 for real in xPos1] 

def conversionAnim(xPos, trueVal, *args):    
    mTuple = [arg for arg in args]
    colorList = ['Green','Blue','Orchid','Cyan','Goldenrod','Salmon','Orange','Violet','Magenta']
    f = pl.figure(figsize =(17,8))
    pl.ion()
    pl.xlim(min(xPos)-1, max(xPos)+1)
    pl.ylim(min(j for i in mTuple for j in i)-.5, max(j for i in mTuple for j in i)+.5)
    for i in range(len(xPos)):
        print '\ni = %i' % i 
        for j in range(len(mTuple)):
            m = mTuple[j]            
            mVal = [element for element in m] 
            print 'Value%i is %s' %(j,mVal[i])       
            if i == 0:
                pl.hold(True)
                pl.scatter(xPos[i],mVal[i],s=50, marker = 'o', color = 'Dark'+colorList[j])
                pl.plot(xPos[i],trueVal[i])                
            else:

                pl.scatter(xPos[i],mVal[i],s=50, marker = 'o',color = 'Dark'+colorList[j])                
                pl.scatter(xPos[i-1], mVal[i-1],s=50, marker = 'o', color = 'white')
                pl.scatter(xPos[i-1], mVal[i-1],s=50, marker = 'x', color = colorList[j])                
                pl.plot(xPos[i-1:i+1],trueVal[i-1:i+1], color = 'red')       

            pl.draw()
        time.sleep(.01)
    time.sleep(3)  # to hold figure after its shown

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conversionAnim(xPos1, trueVal1, m1, m2, m3)
```

I don't know how to get around `ion()` and make this function efficient.

Comment: @cosmosis thanks for the comment. I asked a few questions recently,  although accepted most, some of them still got no answer. This is the way how acceptance is calculated. Nothing can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to make this more efficent is to use 2N line plots instead of a huge number of `scatter` plots.  (It looks like you end up with three scatter plot for every data point!)

As a side note, you have several lines ( `mTuple = [arg for arg in args]`) that turn tuples in to `list`s.  It is clearer to write `mTuple = list(args)`, but I don't think you actually need to do those conversions, as you just need an iterable for everything you do.

```
import itertools

def covnersion_Anim(xPos,trueVal,*args):
    mTuple = args
    plt_bulk_lst = []
    plt_head_lst = []
    color_list = ['Green','Blue','Orchid','Cyan','Goldenrod','Salmon','Orange','Violet','Magenta']
    f = plt.figure(figsize =(17,8))
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_xlim([min(xPos),max(xPos)])
    ax.set_ylim([0,1])
    ms = 5
    for j,c in zip(range(len(mTuple)),itertools.cycle(color_list)):
        plt_bulk_lst.append(ax.plot([],[],color=c,ms=ms,marker='x',linestyle='none')[0])
        plt_head_lst.append(ax.plot([xPos[0]],[mTuple[j][0]],color='Dark'+c,ms=ms,marker='o',linestyle='none')[0])
    real_plt, = plot([],[],color='red')

    for j in range(1,len(xPos)):
        print j
        for hd_plt,blk_plt,m in zip(plt_head_lst,plt_bulk_lst,mTuple):
            hd_plt.set_xdata([xPos[j]])
            hd_plt.set_ydata([m[j]])

            blk_plt.set_ydata(m[:j])
            blk_plt.set_xdata(xPos[:j])

            real_plt.set_xdata(xPos[:j])
            real_plt.set_ydata(trueVal[:j])

        plt.pause(1)

    return f
covnersion_Anim(range(12),rand(12),rand(12),rand(12),rand(12))
```